# map on web page with current location and marked location

Tags: javascript, html

I want the users of my webpage to be able to see an embedded google map with their location and a specified marked location.

Comment: Have you bothered with any of the simple examples lovingly crafted by google for you? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into the API @ Google Maps Platform. This site has a working example of the user's location, I would think it should be pretty easy to add a marked location to this. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation

Comment: Please give a read to [answer], specifically the part titled "Answer well-asked questions".

Answer (score 0):

A comprehensive guide on retrieving the user's location in browser - including how to display the location within a Google Map and necessary fallback considerations.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Then there's the Google Maps Api embed tool that's well documented to allow you to easily change the map as needed.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start

Comment: Please don't recommend w3schools, which has no affiliation with the w3c.

Comment: This is a bad answer because answers are supposed to contain the answer, not link to it. It's also an answer to a bad question, and shouldn't exist in the first place. I didn't mention any of that, didn't even flag it, but merely pointed out that w3schools is a bad resource and shouldn't be recommended to beginners. No need to get all defensive. Further reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com